# Change tables generated by Entity Framework and Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, t4

I know that you can change T4 templates used to generate the classes using Entity Framework 5.0 if you are using Model First. How would you change the template used to generate the tables when you use code first?

Comment: why would you need to with code-first?

Comment: Linq uses entity classes and not tables for CRUD. so why would u want to change any table information. just a thought. and tables are not partial classes. entity classes are partial classes which support inheritance.

Comment: The reason I want to change the generated SQL (and tables) is that I want to automatically create a history table that shadows the main table for every entity. Inserts, updates, and deletes would be inserts in the history table. The generated sql would also create triggers for automatically populating the history table.

Answer (score 1):

When using Code First there are no templates to generate tables. To set table names you can use [TableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.tableattribute) or configure the table for the given entity with [ToTable method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679488%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) in your [OnModelCreating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679267%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) override.